# Keep view above animation of another view

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

I have an `Activity` with a main screen that simply has a title bar (among other things).  I have another `TextView` below the title bar that I have animate from top to bottom into place (it starts out as `View.GONE`, then I animate it visible and into place after an event from the user).

This works fine and dandy, except the `TextView` below the title bar animates above the title bar into place.  I want it to seem as if the `TextView` came from *underneath* the title bar. Both views are in a `LinearLayout`, so I'm not able to address the z-order like I would in a `FrameLayout`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved this by encompassing the textview inside of a LinearLayout, then setting a LayoutAnimationController to the LinearLayout.  This causes all the childs to be animated with respect to the parent container, which made the drop-down only to be rendered within the LinearLayout (which worked perfectly).  Here is the code I used for the Animation Controller and ListView:

```
private void addDeleteDropAnimation() {
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(150);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
    );
    animation.setDuration(300);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    controllerDel = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
    vw_delLinearLayout.setLayoutAnimation(controllerDel);
}
```

Comment: Hi, even if I've been stuck at a similar problem. I tried your solution but didn't work. What could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xx);
        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){            
                tv.setVisible(View.Visible);
            }
        }
        int height = params.height;
        for(int i = 0; i < height + 1; i++) {
            params.topMargin = i - height;
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){            
                   tv.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            try{
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
        }

    }
}.start();
```

you can try this.

Comment: This code seems like manual code for an animation... I can achieve the same thing using an Animation object along with the startAnimation() method, can't I?  Is there any reason to believe that the textview drawn by your code will render underneath the title bar in my application?

Comment: When the view do animation. the property will not change.
Why not try it first.